# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Actions) specified for Copyrightrece

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models

I want to create 2 models in models.py and  2 forms in forms.py for webpage.
but it  shows unknown field error
#models.py

```
class Copyrightapp(models.Model):
   Sno = models.IntegerField()
class Copyrightrece(models.Model):
  Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Actions) specified for Copyrightrece –

Answer (score -1):

The class has to have properties or at least a placeholder:

```
class Copyrightapp(models.Model):
   pass


class Copyrightrece(models.Model):
   pass
```

You could follow the nice [django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/) where you see examples like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: class Copyrightapp(models.Model):
    Sno = models.IntegerField()
    Work = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Authors = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Applied_on = models.CharField(max_length=200)  

class Copyrightrece(models.Model):
    SNo = models.IntegerField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Institute = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                                               
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Actions) specified for Copyrightrece

Comment: could you please format the `code` as "code"?

Comment: i can provide anydesk